# Why was the inverse sine ratio used? and not sine?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

From what point should I look when determining what trig ratio to use? If they can use hypotenuse over opposite, they can also use opposite over hypotenuse. Were should I look to determine the correct ratio? In relation to what point? The angle?

Comment: If they used sine then you would have $$\dfrac 5y=\sin70^\circ.$$ But that's just equivalent to $$\dfrac y5=\dfrac1{\sin70^\circ}.$$

Comment: @Hakim If I want to leave the y at the numerator, how do I know that i have to use the inverse sine ratio then?

Comment: Even if $y$ wasn't at the numerator, you can always take the inverse of both sides as I showed in my previous comment. So you wouldn't have to choose between whether you choose the inverse of sine or sine.

Comment: Also, please note that $\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ would be more accurately described as the reciprocal of the sine, not the inverse. Saying "inverse" could add confusion due to the existence of the inverse of the sine function, $\arcsin$ or $\sin^{-1}$. (The exponent of -1 indicates the inverse function in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just write $$5=y\sin 70^{\circ}$$ as a first step, which is simple and equivalent to the other expressions.

You know to use the sine function because you are dealing with the opposite and the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0):

How the book solved your question:

Start by writing a ration involving $y$.

For example, $\frac{y}{5}$. Now, I see that $5$ is the length of the opposite catete of the angle I know, so this means $\frac{y}{5} = \frac{\text{hyppotenuse}}{\text{opposite}}$. But I know that $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hyppotenuse}}$, meaning that $$\frac{y}{5} = \frac{\text{hyppotenuse}}{\text{opposite}} = \frac{1}{\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hyppotenuse}}} = \frac{1}{\sin 70}$$
Now, if you want to calculate, $y$, just multiply the equation by $5$ to get $$y=\frac{5}{\sin 70}$$

---

Another way you could solve this:

Start with what you have. You have one angle, one (opposite) line and you want the hyppotenuse. What is the equation that connects these three things? Well, you know that $$\sin\alpha = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hyppotenuse}}$$ and you know that $\text{opposite}=5$ and $\text{hyppotenuse} = y$, so $$\sin70=\frac{5}{y}$$
Now, solve this equation for $y$:
$$y\sin 70 = 5\\y=\frac{5}{\sin 70}$$
same as before.

Answer (score 0):

In question like these and many other trigonometric question, I recommend change of perspective. You can rotate the triangle so that the $90^\circ$ angle lies on the horizontal pointing upwards, and then you can visualize the ratios and angle in a better way.

In this diagram, $y$ is hypotenuse and 5 is the perpendicular opposite to $70^\circ$ angle.

$\therefore \sin 70^\circ=\large \frac{5}y$

Then it is just transposition, so that the same is written as

$ y=\large \frac{5}{\sin 70^\circ}$

which is, $y=5\times cosec70^\circ$

Secondly, No matter which ratio you choose, depending on the angle the value of $y$ will remain the same.
You can calculate $y$ using $cosine$ as well(try it for fun).